# Recurring functions in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I try to develop a little browser game based on NodeJS and Angular 4. 
I have an API server running on NodeJS which is connected to a MongoDB and a second server running Angular 4.

I want to execute recurring standard functions (like every 15 minutes) in the background.

Do I need a third server which runs that functions? Or can I run that functions independently on my API server - no matter which route is open?

Comment: you mean calling the certain api every 15 minutes

Comment: I mean, getting data from the DB and do something with it and save the update; e.g.: check all 15 mins if a player has a mine, then increase his/her resources by 1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look to this library [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron). You can set it up to work with your services. You will need to initialise the job right after your sever is initialised. An example:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 30 11 * * 1-5',
  onTick: function() {
    /*
     * Runs every weekday (Monday through Friday)
     * at 11:30:00 AM. It does not run on Saturday
     * or Sunday.
     */
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
job.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. It help that you told me where to place the code. I go with setInterval, but CronJob looks like a good tool too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` in Node just like in the browser:

```
setInterval(() => {
  // this runs every 15 minutes
}, 15 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: sure, thanks for your comment! but I worry about the function when the API is on "/whatever". Is it still working?